# How to pass post method response value through another post method request value

Tags: jmeter

In Jmeter, how to use AUTH “access_token” for passing through header for another POST request ? Below are the step that i have done but it's not working ... [image]How to use "access_token" value, that will use another post request dinamically ? Attached issues is here...

enter image description here

[image]

Comment: I have solved this issue through simple way.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add jp@gc-JSON Path Extractor in HTTP request, the particular HTTP request which is generating access token in its response data .
If response is like - {"access_token":"f5b06970-f00f-4b44-89c8-305738e19cba"}

In JSON path extractor add

1. Variable name -  access_token (variable in which access_token  will be stored)

2.JSON Expression - $.access_token (this will varry according to json response)

3.Default Value - NOT_FOUND

Now the next step is to use this variable named "access_token ". You can use it in your HTTP request for which you need to pass access token under HTTP header manager as  access_token   =    ${access_token }

below link will help you a lot:

https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/advanced-usage-json-path-extractor-jmeter